# COM Interop .Net - Out of Memory/BUFFER OVERFLOW error when executing asm method

Tags: .net, asp-classic, com-interop, out-of-memory

This is a strange one.  For a long time now an application I develop on has been using com interop to use .Net types in an Classic ASP application.  I fired this application up again today to look at some issue with it got an Out Of Memory error when accessing a method on one of these objects.  Fine - I thought, I'll just unregister the lot, check for duplicate entries (for later versions perhaps) in the registry, ensure only the version I am expecting is in the GAC etc etc and try again.  No luck.  Ok, next step can a basic VB6 app do this task; answer? yes! Now I'm confused.  I see nothing in the Fusion logs about this.  Here is the following very simple code used in both the asp and the VB6 form to test this:

```
**VB6**
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim dsf As MyTypeName
    Set dsf = CreateObject("MyNS.MyType")
    dsf.MyMethod "SOME TEXT" ' Works fine in VB6
End Sub

**ASP**
    Dim dsf
    Set dsf = Server.CreateObject("MyNS.MyType")
    dsf.MyMethod "SOME TEXT" ' Doesn't work in asp...
```

The exact error:

Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A0007)
Out of memory: 'MyMethod'

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

Does your `MyMethod` access large amounts of data (maybe an array)?

I did find this from [aspfan - why-do-i-get-errors-in-the-800a0001-800a000f](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-i-get-errors-in-the-800a0001-800a000f-range.html)

Search for your error code.